# How to modify URL manager to accept only numbers and not alphabets in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I am working on a project in yii and I am stuck with some kind a issue while when managing Url Manager. Here is the  Yii's default given **Url manager** code

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```

Now the problem is with the URLs that take id as an argument. Suppose if my Url is

```
localhost/project/admin/showMe/view/id/24
```

then it will take me to the desired place.
**But the problem** with the above URL manager is that if i will use the URL like `localhost/project/admin/showMe/view/id/24someAlphabets`
**then also it takes me to the desired position** because the URL manager finds the numbers.
**Question:-**
 So how can i change the URL manager so that it could take me to the desired place only if i pass the numbers and not the alphabets?

Answer (score 1):

`\d+` will match any number in the string, and will ignore any other letters. If you only want to match numbers and nothing else, you have to use start of string (`^`) and end of string (`$`) anchors:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:^\d+$>'=>'<controller>/view',
```